# Websocket server with Self-Signed certificates in intranet application

Tags: ssl, web, websocket, ssl-certificate

I have an intranet application that runs over https and it needs to access a websocket sever that needs to runs over wss because chrome mixed content security. Both applications use self-signed certificates but is not possible to access the websocket server because chrome doesn't trust in self-signed certificate unless user authorize. So, cause of that the connection fails. Is there a way to have a valid certificate to use in intranet application? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a certificate for websocket.intranet.example.com with a public DNS that doesn't point to the real websocket server, and then copy that certificate in the real server.

Of course, your internal DNS resolver must point websocket.intranet.example.com  to the real websocket server